# unable to parse date in python pandas

Tags: pandas, date

I have column date values as below in the dataframe

```
Jan 2009
Feb 2003
2017-09-01 00:00:00
```

but when I use

```
np.where(df['Date'].astype(str).apply(len) == 8,pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="%b %Y"),pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
```

it fails with the below error:-

ValueError: time data datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 0, 0) does not match format '%b %Y' (match)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some datetimes in format `YYYYMMDD`, so length is `8` so not matched `%b %Y`:

```
print (df)
                  Date
0             20170901
1             Jan 2009
2             Feb 2003
3  2017-09-01 00:00:00
```

For me working only [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print (df)
        Date
0 2017-09-01
1 2009-01-01
2 2003-02-01
3 2017-09-01
```